# Tilde expansion in quotes

Tags: bash

I write a script where must find some files in a user-defined directory which may contain tilde (thus, it's possible to have `user_defined_directory='~/foo'`). The construct looks like

```
found_files=$(find "$user_defined_directory" -type f … )
```

I use quotes to cover possible spaces in that path, but tilde expansion does not work in quotes according to man page. I know about `:` operator that probably can do this expansion, but I can’t figure out how to use it here.

The ‘user-defined-directory’ is being taken from another configuration file in user $HOME directory. It is not passing to my script as a parameter, it’s being parsed from that another config in the script I write.

Comment: How about using eval?  `user_defined_directory=$(eval echo "'$user_defined_directory'")`

Comment: @vaughn-cato no, variable contains the same value it has before.

Comment: FYI: There are a number of 'related' question links on the right, and most of them do not help, including: [Tilde expansion in environment variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984074/), [Bash Tilde Expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651856/), [Bash problem with with cd using tilde expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748216/), [Tilde for home directory doesn't expand within quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409024/).  Not a trivial problem!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `"${user_defined_directory/#~/$HOME}"` to replace a "~" at the beginning of the string with the current user's home directory. Note that this won't handle the `~username/subdir` format, only a plain `~`. If you need to handle the more complex versions, you'll need to write a much more complex converter.

Answer (score 7):

This works given some fairly plausible assumptions, but it is far from obvious code (and isn't a one-liner, either):

```
# Working function - painful, but can you simplify any of it?
# NB: Assumes that ~user does not expand to a name with double spaces or
#     tabs or newlines, etc.

expand_tilde()
{
    case "$1" in
    (\~)        echo "$HOME";;
    (\~/*)      echo "$HOME/${1#\~/}";;
    (\~[^/]*/*) local user=$(eval echo ${1%%/*})
                echo "$user/${1#*/}";;
    (\~[^/]*)   eval echo ${1};;
    (*)         echo "$1";;
    esac
}

# Test cases

name1="~/Documents/over  enthusiastic"
name2="~crl/Documents/double  spaced"
name3="/work/whiffle/two  spaces  are  better  than one"

expand_tilde "$name1"
expand_tilde "$name2"
expand_tilde "$name3"
expand_tilde "~"
expand_tilde "~/"
expand_tilde "~crl"
expand_tilde "~crl/"

# This is illustrative of the 'normal use' of expand_tilde function
x=$(expand_tilde "$name1")
echo "x=[$x]"
```

When run on my machine (where there is a user `crl`), the output is:

```
/Users/jleffler/Documents/over  enthusiastic
/Users/crl/Documents/double  spaced
/work/whiffle/two  spaces  are  better  than one
/Users/jleffler
/Users/jleffler/
/Users/crl
/Users/crl/
x=[/Users/jleffler/Documents/over  enthusiastic]
```

The function `tilde_expansion` deals with the various cases separately and differently.  The first clause deals with a value `~` and simply substitutes `$HOME`.  The second is a case of paranoia: `~/` is mapped to `$HOME/`.  The third deals with `~/anything` (including an empty 'anything').  The next case deals with `~user`.  The catch-all `*` deals with everything else.

Note that the code makes the (plausible) assumption that `~user` will not expand to a value containing any double spaces, nor any tabs or newlines (and possibly other space-like characters).  If you have to deal with that, life is going to be hell.

Note the answer to [`chdir()` to home directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493234/chdir-to-home-directory/9493373#9493373), which explains that POSIX requires `~` to expand to the current value of `$HOME`, but `~user` expands to the value of the home directory from the password database.

Comment: Very nice. Possible simplifications: the second case (`\~/`) can be removed, since the third (`\~/*`) handles it ok. If you use my answer (`"${1/#~/$HOME}"`), you could unify the first three cases (although you'd need two patterns in the case, so it's not really much of a simplification and it's far less readable).

Comment: I tried to combine the second and third cases and didn't get the result I expected, but I'll have another go since I may have been fumble-fingering it.  I wasn't delighted with the number of cases, to be polite about it.

Comment: It's working for me without the second. BTW, it's even working with multiple spaces, tabs, and linefeeds in the `~joeuser` cases (except for linefeeds at the end of the path)! Although it does have the usual risks associated with `eval` in cases like `expand_tilde '~$(rm something)'`

Comment: Updated; testing today showed I was suffering from 'late night programming problems' when I was assembling the answer.

Comment: Might consider using `printf %q` to quote the username before handing it to `eval`. That should always be a noop for usernames using only characters in the portable set, but if we're concerned about malicious input...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: AFAICT, `printf` with `%q` is a non-standard extension, presumably for GNU/Linux, compared with the POSIX standard [`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) command.  That's not to say it shouldn't be used where it is available; it just isn't available everywhere, necessarily (for instance, it isn't documented in BSD / Mac OS X `printf` command).

Comment: It's a ksh-ism adopted by bash and zsh, yes. Notably, this is a question tagged bash.

Comment: ...in bash on MacOS, it'll still be the bash-builtin printf in use, so the lack of support in the external `/usr/bin/printf` provided by the OS is rather moot. And the ksh93 build that ships with MacOS actually provides a printf builtin with a %q implementation significantly superior to that of bash (specifically, one that tries harder to generate POSIX-compliant output where possible; AFAIK, the ksh93 implementation may do so entirely without exception).

Comment: (GNU's `/usr/bin/printf` doesn't provide `%q` either, btw, so far as I'm aware).

Answer (score 2):

Tilde definitely doesn't expand inside quote. There might be some other bash trick but what I do in this situation is this:

```
find ~/"$user_defined_directory" -type f
```

i.e. move starting `~/` outside quotes and keep rest of the path in the quotes.

Comment: Ha, if it would be so simple I wouldn’t ask here. The point is that directory _may be_ starting with a tilde and _may not_ as well, leading to some absolute path.

Comment: I cannot, because that way means escaping spaces and other stuff that shell may recognize as a special character. It’s more harder and will take more code than a colon in right place. The idea suggested by @vaughn-cato with pre-parsing user_defined_dir is better as it adds just one move.