# Why doesn't this bit of code work? Setting variables and config file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, configure

I have recently just made this script:

```
 if test -s $HOME/koolaid.txt ; then
  Billz=$(grep / $HOME/koolaid.txt)
  echo $Billz
  else
 Billz=$HOME/notkoolaid
 echo $Billz
 fi



 if test -d $Billz ; then
  echo "Ok"
 else touch $Billz
fi
```

So basically, if the file `$HOME/koolaid.txt` file does NOT exist, then Billz will be set as $HOME/koolaid.txt. It then sucesfully creates the file.

However, if I do make the koolaid.txt then I get this

```
mkdir: cannot create directory : No such file or directory
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: -1 for putting garbage in my eyes. I will not doing efforts to understand what's wrong here while you don't take the small time to read your post before submit it.

Comment: apologies - in a huge hurry - I will clean it up!

Comment: You may find [Tilde expansion in quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858766/tilde-expansion-in-quotes/15859646#15859646) useful and relevant.

Comment: I the question was unable to be answered, why are there two answers with one accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a difference between content of a variable and evaluated content...
if your variable contains a string `$HOME/some` - **you need expand it** to get `/home/login/same`
One **dangerous** method is `eval`.

```
bin=$(grep / ~/.rm.cfg)
eval rbin=${bin:-$HOME/deleted}
echo "==$rbin=="
```

Don't eval unless you're absolutely sure what you evaling...

Comment: I still don't understand why my command doesn't work. I would rather not meddle around in eval for now, especially as I am beginner and as you said it can be dangerous?

Comment: @oOTesterOo because the **string** `$HOME` need to be expanded... see my (working) example..

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple things to fix:

Start your script with a "shebang," such as:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

This way the shell will know that you want to run this as a Bourne shell script.

Also, your conditional at the top of the script doesn't handle the case well in which .rm.cfg exists but doesn't contain a slash character anywhere in it. In that case the rbin variable never gets set.

Finally, try adding the line

```
ls ~
```

at the top so you can see how the shell is interpreting the tilde character; that might be the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quickly reply! I have added the shebang line now. Also, I am assuming that it DOES have the slash character for now. I will try and make this line more specific later, but for now it just seems that it wont even create the directory I want once the variable has been changed.

I still can't find the problem

Comment: What happens with "ls ~" in the script? Is ~ doing what you expect it to?