# Execute commands and arguments from TSV file

Tags: bash, xargs

I have a TSV file where each line represents a command and command line arguments. Like this:

```
ls      ~
cd      /home
cp      dir1    dir2
```

Each line may have a variable number of columns. Each cell may contain spaces, single quotes and double quotes.

What is a nice way to execute this?

Comment: @ShellFish close, but if a cell has spaces in it then they will be treated as separate arguments. I also tried `(IFS=$'\t'; source load.tsv)`

Comment: Yea it wasn't an answer just a pointer, hence the comment. Do `sed -i s/ /\\ /g` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Bash, read into an array with the IFS set to a tab:

```
$ cat data
ls      ~
cd      /home
cp      dir1    dir2
al      a b       c  d  
$ vis -t -n data
ls^I~^J
cd^I/home^J
cp^Idir1^Idir2^J
al^Ia b^I  c  d  ^J
$ while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a xyz; do al "${xyz[@]}"; done < data
ls
~
cd
/home
cp
dir1
dir2
al
a b
  c  d  
$ while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a xyz; do al "${xyz[@]}"; done < data | vis -t -n
ls^J
~^J
cd^J
/home^J
cp^J
dir1^J
dir2^J
al^J
a b^J
  c  d  ^J
$
```

The `vis` program with options `-t -n` prints tabs as `^I` and newlines as `^J` (followed by a newline); the `al` program prints its arguments one per line — it is effectively equivalent to `printf "%s\n" "$@"` (it's actually a very simple C program, but the result is the same).

With real commands in the file to be executed, you'd write:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a xyz; do "${xyz[@]}"; done < data
```

On my machine, I got:

```
$ (while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a xyz; do "${xyz[@]}"; done < data )
ls: ~: No such file or directory
cp: dir1: No such file or directory
a b
  c  d  
$
```

I used a sub-shell because I didn't want to leave my current directory in my main shell, and I don't have a `dir1` to be copied to `dir2`.  Note that the shell did not do tilde-expansion on the results of the parameter expansion, so `ls` got to see an actual tilde, not the value of my home directory.  Fixing the tilde expansion would be painful — excruciatingly painful (see [Tilde expansion in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858766/tilde-expansion-in-quotes/)).  It also means range notation such as `{1..10}` would not be expanded, and that aliases would not be expanded.  See [Shell expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) for what would and would not occur.

Comment: Actually this does not work if one of the arguments is blank. Also, does not work with zsh

Comment: Any sequence of one or more tabs is treated as a single argument separator.  You didn't mention `zsh` in the question; the tags are [tag:bash] and [tag:xargs].  Do you know why it doesn't work in `zsh`?  If you need empty fields respected, then you certainly have to modify this answer; you probably can't do it with shell and IFS.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
ruby -ne 'require "shellwords"; system $_.chomp.split("\t").shelljoin'
```

---

Proof:

Here is our testing script: `cat printArguments.bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
args=("$@")
for ((i=0; i < $#; i++)) {
   echo "argument $((i+1)): ${args[$i]}"
}
```

And the test case:

```
echo $'./printArguments.bash\t1\t\t3' | ruby -ne 'require "shellwords"; system $_.chomp.split("\t").shelljoin'
```

The result:

> argument 1: 1
>
> argument 2:
>
> argument 3: 3