# Why is a tilde in a path not expanded in a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, tilde-expansion

I tried to get the Android Studio launcher (studio.sh) to use my manually installed Java (not the system-wide default Java). Since I already declared `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` in my `.bashrc` file, I simply sourced that file in the shell script:

> . /home/foobar/.bashrc

but for some reason, `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java` was still not recognized as an executable file by the script.

I added some logging and found out that `JAVA_HOME` was expanded as ~/install/java..., i.e. the tilde operator was not expanded into the home directory.

I did some searching, but couldn't find any reason why it was not expanded. Is tilde a Bash-specific feature (the script uses `#!/bin/sh`, and Linux Mint uses dash, not bash)? Does tilde not work in some circumstances?

I replaced `~` with `$HOME` in my `.bashrc` declaration, and then it worked, so HOME is known at runtime.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions), note that brace expansion *during* parameter substitution, but not recursively:

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and filename expansion.

This implies that any tilde (or parameter references or command substitution) stored unexpanded in a bash variable will *not automatically resolve*. Your JAVA_HOME variable contains a literal tilde, so bash will not expand it automatically.

It is likely that your fix worked because tilde expansion does not apply in quotes:

```
$ echo "~"
~
$ echo ~
/home/jeffbowman
```

...but parameter expansion like `$HOME` does occur in quotes. Replacing it with $HOME expands to your home directory *during the assignment of JAVA_HOME*.

```
FOO=~/bar        # stores /home/jeffbowman/bar
FOO="~/bar"      # stores ~/bar
FOO=$HOME/bar    # stores /home/jeffbowman/bar
FOO="$HOME/bar"  # stores /home/jeffbowman/bar
```

Though the better option is to ensure your assignment is correct, if you want to expand it manually, these SO questions have some good options:

- ["Tilde expansion in quotes"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15858766/1426891)
- ["How to manually expand a special variable (ex: ~ tilde) in bash"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3963716/1426891)

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29310477/258523) might be a better one to point at but I haven't really looked at the one you linked too all that carefully.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks. There are a few long-standing "expand my stored tilde" questions that might warrant de-duping. That's a good one; I'll edit it in. (I'd rather link to the question than the answer, because the breadth of answers is useful to understand advantages and disadvantages of each.)

Comment: Yeah, I've had a few tabs of that sort open for a while waiting for me to decide how to de-dupe them well. I almost posted a meta question about whether it would be possible to get a moderator to migrate some of the better answers to a new canonically asked question or something.