# Why is a valid path with a tilde not expanding in this cron job?

Tags: bash, cron

I had the following lines in my crontab:

```
PY=/home/schemelab/install/miniconda/bin/python
ST=~/prg/surgetrader

# SURGE TRADER

00  * * * * cd $ST/src/ ; $PY download.py; $PY scan.py --buy 1
```

And when it ran the error message in my email was:

```
X-Cron-Env: <GT=~/prg/gridtrader>
X-Cron-Env: <AGT=~/prg/adsactly-gridtrader>
X-Cron-Env: <PY=/home/schemelab/install/miniconda/bin/python>
X-Cron-Env: <ST=~/prg/surgetrader>
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/schemelab>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=schemelab>
Date: Sun, 30 Jul 2017 09:50:02 -0400 (EDT)

/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to ~/prg/surgetrader/src/
/home/schemelab/install/miniconda/bin/python: can't open file 'takeprofit.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

However, the path certainly does exist. I think that the tilde is not being expanded or something.

Comment: Btw.: `/bin/sh` is usually not `bash`.

Comment: @Cyrus and even when it's implemented by bash it doesn't act like bash necessarily

Comment: Could you kindly link to me the question that this is a duplicate of?

Answer (score 7):

Tilde `~` resolution is a bash feature. However your cronjob is not executed through Bash (You could do it explicitly if you want). However you can use `$HOME` to refer to the user home independently of the shell.

Refer to [Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) for more info.

Comment: The problem is the order of expansion (tilde expansion before variable expansion) in this line: `cd $ST/src/`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32276909/3776858

Comment: Tilde expansion is not specific to `bash`.

Comment: dang thanks so much.  was using `~`, also `$HOME` did not work in my cron (running as root) - I had to use `/home/pi/foo/bar/path` instead - now works!