# Bash script change directory returns no such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell, cd

I'm working a script that reads back the input of a full path to a directory (e.g. `~/test`) but when I run the shell script it come back with this:

`test-script.sh: line 34: cd: ~/test: No such file or directory`

I'm running the `test-script.sh` file in a different directory, so I was assuming that a simple:

`cd ~/test` in the script would do it, but I guess not.

I know that this is probably a redundant question, but most of the other issues/examples have been with loops and other cases outside of just doing a simple `cd ~/test` in a script.

And for reference this is all I'm doing in my script:

```
echo What directory do you want to change to?

read directory_name

cd $directory_name
```

Again, new to bash/shell scripting so if there are any other ideas or suggestions, I'm all for it. Thanks!

Comment: See: [Why is a tilde in a path not expanded in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32276909/3776858)

Comment: In scripts, use `$HOME` instead of the `~` shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

solution 1)

if you want to use **~** , you need to use eval .

```
#!/bin/bash
pwd
echo What directory do you want to change to?
read directory_name
eval "cd $directory_name"
pwd
```

But this solution is weak , because someone can enter some maliciuois command instead of a directory name and this script will execute .

solution 2) 
check if the first character of directory_name is a **~** and replace it by the appropriate value , it can the current user home dir or another user home dir .

you can do **cd ~** or **cd ~usera**  to change to **usera** homedir

Comment: Gotcha.
I'll dig around to see how to go about checking for that.