# How to source a string path in shell?

Tags: zsh

I want to do things like this:

```
local_config="~/.local_config"
source $local_config
```

But it seems that the string is not treated as a file path.

I'm using Zsh.

Comment: Keep `~` outside quotes to make it: `local_config=~"/.local_config"`

Comment: Yes. That works! It is unexpected that Nobody asked this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tilde expansion in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858766/tilde-expansion-in-quotes)

Comment: There are various `bash` questions, and I (prematurely) voted to close this as a duplicate of one of them, but `zsh` does behave differently enough to warrant leaving this open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~` is not expanded inside the single or double quotes. To make it work, keep `~` outside the quotes as:

```
local_config=~"/.local_config"
```

Comment: Sorry I edited the answer; I missed the `zsh` tag, and `zsh` is more forgiving than `bash` is regarding tilde expansion.

Answer (score 2):

Try without quotes:

```
local_config=~/.local_config
```

or

```
local_config="$HOME/.local_config"
```