# How can I make bash realpath work with variables?

Tags: bash, quotes, realpath, tilde-expansion

I run

```
#!/bin/bash

id="~/.ssh/foo"

realpath ~/.ssh/foo
realpath "~/.ssh/foo"
realpath $id
realpath "$id"
```

expecting 4 identical lines of output, with no errors. What I get is

```
/home/me/.ssh/foo
realpath: '~/.ssh/foo': No such file or directory
realpath: '~/.ssh/foo': No such file or directory
realpath: '~/.ssh/foo': No such file or directory
```

Why does only the first of these succeed?

I want to do

```
echo "Enter a path: "
read p
p="$(realpath "$p")"
echo "The real path is $p"
```

which doesn't work because of this error. What do I need to do?

Comment: Change `id="~/.ssh/foo"` to `id=~/".ssh/foo"`. Otherwise the `~` character isn't expanded to your home directory which causes the failure (unless you have directories having literally a `~` character in their name).

Comment: I need to be able to enter `~/foo` at `read p`

Comment: As a quick solution use `realpath "${p/#\~/$HOME}"`. For going more into detail maybe this will help you: [How to manually expand a special variable (ex: ~ tilde) in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963716/how-to-manually-expand-a-special-variable-ex-tilde-in-bash)

Comment: See [Tilde expansion in environment variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984074/), [Bash Tilde Expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651856/), [Bash problem with with cd using tilde expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748216/), [Tilde for home directory doesn't expand within quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409024/), and [Tilde expansion in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858766/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manually expand a special variable (ex: ~ tilde) in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963716/how-to-manually-expand-a-special-variable-ex-tilde-in-bash)